# Load classification tree model on new raster data set

Tags: r, model, tree, classification, raster

I am working with a classification tree model that allows me to classify raster images (to create maps). I would like to reapply this classification tree to a new raster dataset, in another script.
I tried to save the model as `.rda` or `.RData` file but I have the same problem it's impossible to predict the model on the new dataset.

> no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "character"

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to the `save` function of the model since it does not appear entirely:

```
summary(model)
#   Length     Class      Mode 
#        1 character character
```

I'm saving my model with this code :

```
save(cuttreedown.training, file =("Artmac.rda")
```

and load it with :

```
model <- load("Artmac.rda")
```

And this is my `predict` function where `satImage` is my raster file (the function is working well on another script) :

```
predict(satImage, model, filename="test.tif", progress='text', datatype='INT1U', type='prob', overwrite=TRUE)
```

I just want to apply my model on a new raster dataset as it is done in the training script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use saveRDS/loadRDS for such a task. Here is a full example:

```
library(rpart)

data(iris)
fit <- rpart(Species~., data = iris)

saveRDS(fit, "fit.rds")
load_fit <- readRDS("fit.rds")

all.equal(predict(load_fit, iris),
          predict(fit, iris))
#output
TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

simply save and load the model without an extension. Also, don't create a new object when loading, it will automatically populate the model object into the environment. Try:

```
save(cuttreedown.training, file="Artmac")

load("Artmac")

summary(Artmac)
```

Comment: No it's not working I have exactly the same problem, it's like it's not really saving my model. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Providing a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126) example would help the troubleshooting process.